# Scrolling a DIV container from certain point

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I need help with HTML/JavaScript. I have a DIV with id sideMenu and it's positioned left to the main content, right under a header ([screenshot](http://s30.postimg.org/6vmocysrl/sidemenu.png)), and i need this DIV to start following, when the browser's top border touches this div...

Comment: What you tried to do for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a mocked-up example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/6bK6Q/

Essentially, you need to do something like this:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function (e) {
    var $body = $("body"),
        $header = $("header"),
        $nav = $("nav"),
        $content = $(".content");
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $header.height()) {
        $nav.css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": 0
        });
        $content.css({
            "margin-left": "27%"
        });
    } else {
        $nav.css({
            "position": "static"
        });
        $content.css({
            "margin-left": "2%"
        });
    }
});
```

Hope that gets you headed in the right direction.